# Gaining access to an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios, nib

I am new to arrays and objects. I have a class HowToPlay.h (of course that has a .m also) their i define two arrays

```
NSMutableArray *nibs;
NSMutableArray *unusedNibs;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *nibs;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *unusedNibs;
```

then we jump into the .m, 
i write all the stuff for the arrays,

```
nibs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Question 2", @"Question 3", nil];
self.unusedNibs = nibs;
[nibs release];
```

Then i also have another class called Question 1, i need to be able to use this array in that class, and be able to change it, but keep the changes on the HowToPlay.m file.

here is why, basically this array loads random NIB files, and then deletes them from the array when they have been used.

in Question 1.m here is what im doing to use the array

```
random = arc4random() % [self.unusedNibs count];
NSString *nibName = [self.unusedNibs objectAtIndex:random];
[self.unusedNibs removeObjectAtIndex:random];

if (nibName == @"Question 3") {
    Question_3 *Q3 = [[Question_3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Question 3" bundle:nil];

    Q3.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:Q3 animated:YES];
    [Q3 release];
}

if (nibName == @"Question 2") {
    Question_2 *Q2 = [[Question_2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Question 2" bundle:nil];

    Q2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:Q2 animated:YES];
    [Q2 release];
}
```

This all seems to work fine, but the problem im having is it seems that objects in the array are not getting deleted, even though this line runs

```
[self.unusedNibs removeObjectAtIndex:random];
```

I haved tried making it

```
[HowToPlay.unusedNibs removeObjectAtIndex:random];
```

I get a error saying `expected '.' before '.' token`

It seems to me that i have access to read the array, but not to change it. any way to fix this so i can change the array? thanks

UPDATE:

here is the whole HowToPlay.h file contents:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

int score;
int usedQ1;
int usedQ2;
int usedQ3;
NSMutableArray *nibs;
NSMutableArray *unusedNibs;

@interface HowToPlay : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {


UIPickerView *selectType;
NSMutableArray *selectArray;

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

UIActivityIndicatorView *progress;
UIButton *worldButton;
UIButton *politicsButton;
UIButton *starButton;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *nibs;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *unusedNibs;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *worldButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *politicsButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *starButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *selectType;
@property (nonatomic) int usedQ1;
@property (nonatomic) int usedQ2;
@property (nonatomic) int usedQ3;

@property (readwrite) int score;






-(IBAction)World:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Politics:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Stars:(id)sender;




@end

#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "Question 1.h"
#import "Question 2.h"
#import "Question 3.h"
```

I import after because otherwise i get errors

Also I have the array set up on theViewDidLoad part of HowToPlay, is this a bad idea?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 

    NSURL *click = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/click.wav",         [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:click error:nil];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;




    progress = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    progress.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0);
    progress.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview: progress];

    usedQ1 = 0;
    usedQ2 = 0;
    usedQ3 = 0;


    selectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [selectArray addObject:@"World"];
    [selectArray addObject:@"Politics"];
    [selectArray addObject:@"Stars"];
    score = 0;

    nibs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Question 2", @"Question 3", nil];
    self.unusedNibs = nibs;
    [nibs release];
}
```

Comment: have you tried printing out `count` before and after you remove the item?

Comment: Just an FYI (I don't know if this is the problem), if you use `nibName == @"Question 3"`, that's going to compare pointers, not string contents.  You should be using `isEqualToString:` to compare strings.  Additionally, you should be retaining `nibName` after getting it from the array and before removing it from the array, or it'll be released.

Comment: Actually, there are a bunch of strange things going on in this code.  You might want to take a look at how you're using properties and review the Obj-C memory management docs on ownership.  Currently, you assign an array to the 'nibs' ivar and the unusedNibs `property`, but then you release it, despite the property for `nibs` specifying that whatever goes in its ivar should _also_ be retained.  Also take a look at questions you haven't accepted answers for.

Comment: Okay, changed it to 'isEqualToString' and moved the deletion to the end of the action, still no luck ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you check if objects are actually deleted? Please post some more code as the way you remove objects from unusedNibs seems to be fine. As per this code:

```
[self.unusedNibs removeObjectAtIndex:random];
```

and this code

```
[HowToPlay.unusedNibs removeObjectAtIndex:random];
```

The reason why you're getting this error is because you're trying to access unusedNibs using a class name "HowToPlay" instead of its instance "self".

Comment: How do you pass unusedNibs to your Question 1 class (as you have access to some unusedNibs property there)?

Comment: Question 1 is a subclass of HowToPlay

Comment: Then please explain how and where you check the number of items in this array.

Comment: Well in Question 1, at the ContinueAction, it chooses a random number that is within the ammount of objects in the array  `random = arc4random() % [self.unusedNibs count];` Then it creates the string out of the name of it ` NSString *nibName = [self.unusedNibs objectAtIndex:random];` Then it goes ahead and checks for a match, then deletes whatever object it choose out of the array ` [self.unusedNibs removeObjectAtIndex:random];`

Comment: Yes, I can see that, you wrote it already :) My question was: how do you check the number of items when you remove some of them. Have you tried anything like this:     NSLog(@"Count: %d", [self.unusedNibs count]);
    [self.unusedNibs removeObjectAtIndex:whicheverIndexYouWish];
    NSLog(@"Count: %d", [self.unusedNibs count]);

Comment: I see what you mean, i think i might know the problem, the count starts orginally at 1, then when i delete one it goes to 0. As i recall, you cant pick a random number with 0. So like arc4random() % 0 would give you an error, maybe the app is auto putting a 1 back in it? I added what you said to, and checked the log, whenever it goes to a new viewController, it goes back to 1.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:  first, to call properties like unusedNibs in HowToPlay it looks like you are calling the class and not an instance. You need to create a HowToPlay object and assign it to a property in your Question1 object so the question one Object has something to call to. Question1 should not call 'self' for unusedNibs since it does not own it.

With what you are doing it might make more sense to put the function figuring out the next random controller in the HowToPlay class. That way your question view controllers could just ask it to return which controller is next without having to duplicate that code across every question controller.

Comment: So if i put the change NIB action in the HowToPlay class, would their be a way to use it from another class? Thanks

Comment: Absolutely. Create an object and assign it to a property and you can access its methods.

Comment: how would you do that exactly? :) thanks, you dont need to use any of my variables and stuff, just a generic example please. Thanks!

Comment: [myHowToPlayObject nextController];